# skrollr.js: Turn off or destroy skrollr at a given window width

Tags: javascript, scroll, responsive-design, parallax

I'm using [skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to animate a few things on a page. I'd like to only initialize skrollr when the window viewport width is larger than a particular size, and completely remove it or destroy it when I'm below that viewport width.

For instance, when the browser window width is greater than 600px, I want skrollr to be initialized, but when the browser's window width is less than 600px, I want to turn off or destroy skrollr.

Comment: Is it OK to have this check at page load or does it need to react to window resize?

Comment: It will need to react to window resize. I'm already using [jRespond](https://github.com/ten1seven/jRespond) elsewhere on the site, so if it helps, I can listen for specific mediaquery "breakpoints".

Comment: If you want it dynamic, you're out of luck. https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/202 https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/109

Comment: Thank you for posting those links.

Comment: #109 is fixed. There's now a `destroy` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `destroy` instance method is what you are looking for. I've been working on it on last weeks and now it looks like Prinzhorn already merged my changes on the master branch.

Hope to be helpful, cheers!

Comment: Marked as accepted, as I'm 99% sure this is what I was looking for. The project has since gone to production, but this is great for the future! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kordero, I have used skrollr for a site and all works fine, but I don't want the animation to reverse while scrolling up. how to use the dest0ory method

Comment: sorry San, missed your comment, you should call to the `instance.destroy()` method from the `instance` object (the one returned when you make your call to skrollr.init). Then you should manage to re-initialize a new skrollr instance when scrolling down after that or something. I must warn you that destroying it means that any change on the UI made by skrollr will be undone, so implications may unhandled vary, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) *(and Yepnope.js)* to test a given media query, then, if it returns true, import the script. This is documented [here](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq).

So, for instance:

```
Modernizr.load([
  {
    test: Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 600px)'),
    yep: '/js/skrollr.js',
  }
]);
```

Comment: This is fine for loading Skrollr at a particular breakpoint, but I was looking for a way to completely destroy the instance at a particular breakpoint once it was already initialized. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Use the skrollr.destroy() function in combination with [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) (mediaqueries for js).

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 960px)", {

    match : function() {
        var s = skrollr.init();
    },      

    unmatch : function() {
        var s = skrollr.destroy();
    },    

    deferSetup : true,

});
```